# How do I obtain a stack trace for this exception?

Tags: java, log4j

```
15:31:58,339 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl:211 - Closing prepared statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@7bf4109: select producttyp0_.id as id5_, producttyp0_.name as name5_ from production_queue.Product_Type producttyp0_ where producttyp0_.name='Phone Case']
15:31:58,339 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler:88 - Handling invocation of statement method [invalidate]
15:31:58,339 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:234 - Starting after statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
15:31:58,339 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext:1016 - Initializing non-lazy collections
15:31:58,339 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl:1383 - Setting cache mode to: NORMAL
15:31:58,339 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl:340 - Closing session
15:31:58,340 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:193 - Closing logical connection
15:31:58,340 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler:110 - Handling invocation of connection method [close]
15:31:58,340 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler:206 - Invalidating connection handle
15:31:58,340 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl:205 - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl@4557b620]
15:31:58,340 DEBUG Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:314 - Releasing JDBC connection
15:31:58,341 DEBUG Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:332 - Released JDBC connection
15:31:58,341 DEBUG Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler:219 - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
15:31:58,341 TRACE Grizzly(1) org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl:207 - Logical connection closed
WARNING: Exception during FilterChain execution
WARNING: service exception
```

Despite having `log4j.rootCategory=TRACE, stdout` configured, it doesn't seem to help me get more details on this exception.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootCategory=TRACE, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %t %c:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Show your log4j.properties or log4.xml file.

Comment: Please provide a better title.

Comment: @Raedwald - Good call, thanks!  I meant to go back and improve that title but never got to it.

Comment: Just because you've configured the logger itself doesn't mean whoever made the call included the whole `Throwable` object as a separate parameter. It looks like they just did `warn(e)`, which uses the exception message and nothing else (I assume this is where "service exception" came from).

Comment: @TomG - Can you post that as an answer?  Looks like I'll have to add a debug line and just step by step till I see where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logger looks properly configured, but that doesn't mean that the problematic code calls it correctly. If the logger is simply called as `LOG.warn(e)` it will log only the message of the exception, not the full stack trace.

Thinking about it, though, it's odd that the timestamp and class file aren't present in the log. Are you sure Grizzly uses Log4J and isn't doing its own logging via commons-logging or Java Util Logging?

Comment: Ohhhh you're right.  I turned those off!  I had totally forgotten about that.  Duh!